# Select rows based on JSON item value

Tags: mysql

I am storing my payload like this:

column name will be payload.

```
{
    "ordernumber":"PO_13122",
    "itemno":"44655644",
    "description":"item001",
    "quantity":"1"
}
```

Now I want to fetch the data based on the `ordernumber`. How can I do that?

Comment: What's your mysql version?

Comment: SQL yog community -MYSQL GUI v12.4.3

Comment: MySQL - 10.1.26-MariaDB

Answer (score 1):

Your data of column is JSON format if your mysql version heigher than 5.7 you can try to use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-extract) method.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(payload, '$.ordernumber') 
FROM T
```

[sqlfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ejGLRLvbNo3Xx3XCuG89pw/0)

Comment: Can i add where clause there??

Comment: Sure you can use in `WHERE` clause directly https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ejGLRLvbNo3Xx3XCuG89pw/1   ... @HelloWorld

Comment: hi thank u so much ...
I am getting this error "JSON_EXTRACT does not exist". when i execute the query .

Comment: Would you consider  update the version higher than MariaDB 10.2.3? Because the higher version support some useful function for json.

Comment: Thank you so much. i will update the version and try this

Comment: If your version heigher than 10.2.3. you also can use JSON_VALUE function to do it

https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/json_value/

Comment: hi @ D-shih . i was using online compiler. i just need an query  where i will pass this order number and item no extracted from JSON_EXTRACT in where condition and get the all records which are satisfying the both conditions.

Comment: @D-shih Thank you so  much .. i am able to update the version and get the data.

Comment: @BhavaniSankar No problem glad to help, you can mark this answer if that help you :)

Answer (score 0):

MySQL version>=5.7 support json data storing

```
insert into user values (NULL,
'{"name":"David","mail":"jiangchengyao@gmail.com","address":"Shangahai"}');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using at least MySQL v8, or MariaDB v10.2 or later you should look into using Virtual Columns. This allows you to define a column as a function of a JSON field. The virtual columns can also be indexed for optimal query performance.

```
ALTER TABLE orders ADD order_number VARCHAR(100) AS (JSON_VALUE(orders->"$.ordernumber")) 
CREATE INDEX orders_idx1 ON orders (order_number)
```

Now you able to use the Virtual Column (order_number) as you would any other column.

```
SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_number = 1;
```

There are good online resources for both [MySQL](https://mysqlserverteam.com/indexing-json-documents-via-virtual-columns/) and [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/resources/blog/json-mariadb-102).

(disclaimer; I didn't run any of the above queries and don't use MariaDB)